# Beginner linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am a bit confused on trying to prove a result in linear algebra. I will most what I know but I think it is very incomplete etc.

$\mathbf{Thereom}:$  Let $A \in \mathbb{M_{nxn}}$, and v an eigenvector of A associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then the following hold,

(i) If $p(t) \in P$ ( that is $p(t)$ is a polynomial) then this $\rightarrow p(A)v=p(\lambda)v$

(ii) $\lambda$ is a root of the minimal polynomial, $m(t)$ of A.

I know that we have,  $Av=\lambda v$, and I know a few other thermos such as the characteristic polynomial of A and the minimal polynomial have the same irreducible factors, and that the minimal polynomial divides every polynomial that has A has a zero.

That is I know that m(t) divides the polynomial obtained by solving $|A-\lambda I|v=0$

and even further that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A implies it is a root of the minimal polynomial. But I am having trouble tiring it all together. Is there any other things I should be considering? Thank you

Comment: As for (i), try to write the polynomial as a sum of powers and go from there. As for (ii), when I took the course, we showed that $p(x)$ divides $m(x)^n$ and this implies what you want.

Comment: What is $P$? What is the $\rightarrow$ doing there? What is $\mathbb M_{nxn}$?

Comment: @Myridium , I think it is pretty well understand that it is the space of matrices of size n by n..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a)

Note that $Av=\lambda v$, then $AAv=A\lambda v=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$. Following inductively, you will find that $A^nv=\lambda^nv$. Now let's take a polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$. We have that $$P(A)=a_nA^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1A+a_0I$$ is of course a linear operator. If now we let $$P(A)v=a_nA^nv+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}v+\ldots+a_1Av+a_0Iv,$$ what are we going to get?

For b)

Put $m(t)$ as the minimum polynomial of A and $q(t)$ it´s characteristic polynomial. By the Hamilton-Cayley theorem, we have that $m(t)|q(t)$, then a root of $m(t)$ will be a root for $q(t)$.

Now let's take an eigenvalue, say $\lambda$.

We know that $m(A)=0$ because $m(t)$ is the minimal polynomial, but if v is the eigenvector associated to $\lambda$ ($v\neq 0$) then $$0=m(A)v=m(\lambda)v$$ so as $v\neq 0$, it turns out that $m(\lambda)=0$, i.e., $\lambda$ is a root for the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

For (i): first show that $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Next, write $p(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_k\,t^k$ where $a_k$ are suitable scalars from your field. Then consider $$\Bigl(p(A)-p(\lambda)I\Bigr) v\,,$$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and see what you can say about it.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\lambda, \vec v$ an eigenvalue-eigenvector pair. Since by definition $A\vec v = \lambda \vec v$, and since $\lambda \vec v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$, $A(A\vec v) = \lambda^2\vec v$. In general $A^n\vec v = \lambda^n\vec v$. So for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ we have
$$ (A^n - \lambda^nId) \vec v = \vec 0.$$

For $\text{(i)}$ notice that since $p(A) = c_0 Id +c_1A+\cdots+c_nA^n$ we have $p(A)\vec v = c_0 Id \vec v + c_0 A\vec v + c_0 A^n\vec v$ which by above is equal to  $c_0\vec v + c_1\lambda \vec v+\cdots+c_n\lambda^n\vec v$, as desired.

Now consider some polynomial $S(t) = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2 + \cdots + c_nt^n$. Then we have $S(A)\vec v = S(\lambda)\vec v$.

For $\text{(ii)}$: If we pick $S\in \Sigma$ (the set of polynomials that vanish on $A$), then, $S(A) = 0 \implies S(\lambda) = 0$. So all polynomials that vanish on $A$ also vanish on its eigenvalues. And the minimal polynomial is defined as $m\in \Sigma$ with minimal degree.